# Filosofical: A behaviour change should be requested by a client or set up in the service?

Tags: aws-lambda, architecture, serverless

I manage a serverless service with specific rules for accessing downstream services. One rule limits querying a data-source (let's call it YR - from Year Review) to a specific date range, from 02-JAN to 31-JAN (regardless of the year).

One of our consumers wishes to test this functionality on 10-DEC-2023, a date outside the availability range. To facilitate this, we introduced a behavior switch—a HEADER enabling the override of the current date for rule evaluation. If this header is set to a particular date, say 10-JAN, the rule will use that date as NOW and retrieve the YR data source accordingly.

Now, this consumer wants me to convert the date range (02-JAN to 31-JAN) into an environment variable. They argue that it will enable them to modify the range for testing purposes and revert it afterward. However, I believe this approach is problematic as it could impact other consumers relying on this service. I feel the behavior switch should suffice for the test without affecting others.

My Product Owner (P.O.) and tech lead insist that establishing environment variables will be helpful and have asked me to comply, suggesting that I'm inflexible. Am I mistaken in my stance?